# Convert month number to month short name

Tags: php

I have a variable with the following value

```
$month = 201002;
```

the first 4 numbers represent the year, and the last 2 numbers represent the month. I need to get the last 2 numbers in the month string name eg. Feb

My code looks like this

```
<?php echo date('M',substr($month,4,6)); ?>
```

I can I go about to obtain the month name

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert month-number to short month-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612012/php-convert-month-number-to-short-month-name)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Append "01" and strtotime will be able to parse the string :

```
echo date('M', strtotime($month . '01'));
```

Comment: @Roland: 02 = Jan, 03 = Feb, ..., 13 = Dec

Answer (score 7):

The second parameter of date is a timestamp.
Use [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to create one.

```
$month = 201002;
$monthNr = substr($month, -2, 2);

$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNr, 1);
$monthName = date('M', $timestamp );
```

Comment: The second parameter of `substr` is length, not end position. You can also seek from the end, using `substr($month, -2, 2)`.

Comment: Why would you say `2 = Jan`? It is not true. In this particular case it is true, but *only* because you create the timestamp for day 0, and not day 1, which means the last day of the previous month. `mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNr, 1)` will create a timestamp for the 1st day of the month, current year.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you..

```
  $month = substr($month, -2, 2);
  echo date('M', strtotime(date('Y-'. $month .'-d')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DateTime Class to get a Date data structure using date string and format. Then get a date string with any format like this:

```
$month = 201002; 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Yd', $month);  
$monthName = $date->format('M'); // will get Month name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mydate = "201002";
date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, substr($mydate, 4, 2), 1, 2000));
```

Answer (score -2):

Being a programmer, and even knowing nothing of PHP data magic, I'd made it

```
$month = intval(substr($input_date,4,2));
$mons = explode(" ","Zer Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec");
echo $mons[$month];
```

Comment: Poor August and September. :(

Comment: It should be substr($strange_date,4,2), because the third parameter is the lenght...

Comment: It's concise and simple, but isn't friendly for localization / internationalization. Better to use date() and get the month name in the user's language. Better still to let someone else write all our date code, because it's a Pandora's box.

Comment: When we have default methods why we add more code