# PHP convert month-number to short month-name

Tags: php

I need to convert month-number to short month-name (i.e., 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb)

I know that I can achieve this via Array, but is there any other way to do it?

Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes there is. Use [date](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)/[stftime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php) in combination with [mktime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) to create a timestamp within the desired month.

Strftime is cool because it will read the locale setting, and output your written date parts in that specific language.

For example:

```
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNumber);
$name = strftime("%b", $time);
```

Now lets say you want your short month names in german language you call [setlocale](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.setlocale.php) before calling strftime:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {
  echo date ("M", mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,0))."<br />";
}
```

Without the `for` loop, for month 6:

```
  echo date ("M", mktime(0,0,0,6,1,0));
```