# How is convert month number to month short name?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

For example my month number is (`3` = Mar) Or (`2` = Feb), i tryed as following code, but it doesn't work. How fix it?

```
$month = 2; 
echo date('M', strtotime($month));
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZKctjg

Comment: this has already been asked :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943292/convert-month-number-to-month-short-name
and here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612012/php-convert-month-number-to-short-month-name

Comment: this has already been asked

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943292/convert-month-number-to-month-short-name

Comment: this has already been asked

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943292/convert-month-number-to-month-short-name

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612012/php-convert-month-number-to-short-month-name

Comment: @user690936: please don't stop! we didn't get it at the first time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
$month = 2; 
echo date('M', strtotime('2012-' . $month . '-01'));
```

`strtotime()` accepts date not just month